# Can't access to Firebase Storage in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, storage

I want to access to a folder in my firebase storage so i'm using this flutter code to do that

```
`
  var storageRef =
     firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('test');
  storageRef.listAll().then((value) {
     value.items.forEach((element) {
   print(element.getDownloadURL().toString());`
  });`
});`
```

and I set all my files and folders as a publicly by this code

`allow read, write : if true ;`

but I get this message in my terminal

W/StorageUtil(28332): no auth token for request

I think its seems like I have to authenticate my users but in my use case I don't must do it

additionally by set my files and folders publicly I don't need to authenticate my users

what is wrong in my code or in my logic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my issue, first the message that I get in terminal 'W/StorageUtil(28332): no auth token for request' is not an error but a debug message, so the mistake that I have made is I print getDownloadURL() without await statement so I have changed my code in forEach loop to be like that

`var x = await element.getDownloadURL();  print(x);`

Answer (score 0):

The message " W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request " is key for debugging this issue.

This log message means that Firebase Storage did not see *any* login in the current context.  This includes anonymous logins.  It means that no authorization was passed to the backend and the only way this will be allowed is if you set your rules to be completely open (public access) which is not recommended (see below).

```
 //this sets completely open access to your data
 allow read, write;
```

I would review the code you have for logging in and ensure it successfully completes before any storage operation is done.
If you are sure your auth code is correct, try [resetting data on the device](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-clear-app-cache-and-app-data-in-android-6-0-marshmallow/) so that no saved state might be there to mess up the application's authorization information.

You might have to check your RULES for storage in firebase console. By default it is set to only permit to authenticated user only like this

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ,as I have said, I set all my files publicly by allow read, write;  , also in my use case  I don't need to authenticate my user to use my app